# CSS - селекторы: больше подробностей или меньше?

Tags: html, css, теория

Предположим, есть такая разметка:

```html
<header id="header">
  <div class="header-top">
    <div class="callus">+0 000 0000 00</div>
  </div>
</header>
```

И есть несколько вариантов:

```css
.callus {}

#header .callus {}

.header-top .callus {}

#header .header-top .callus {}
```

Я обычно на сайтах наблюдаю **первый вариант**. Но мне кажется это не слишком хорошей идеей по 2 причинам:

1. Большой шанс конфликта с будущими доработками (другому человеку придется веселиться с вашими стилями, даже если он просто хочет добавить, а не изменить что-то)
2. При добавлении новости/поста на сайт, визуальный редактор может добавить какое-то свое оформление или теги(с чем я лично много раз сталкивался).

**Второй вариант**, вроде-бы, конкретизирует: нам нужны элементы в шапке. Но при большом уровне вложенности движок делает большой путь от каждого из элементов с классом `callus` до самого верха, пока не найдет элемент с id `header`

**Третий вариант** - нечто среднее между 1 и 2. Вроде-бы и решает проблему, но шанс ошибки остается.

**Четвертый вариант** называют *переизбыточными селекторами*, если не ошибаюсь. И да, это плохо.

Что посоветуете по поводу селекторов? То что названия классов должны максимально отражать суть элемента, это понятно. А что по поводу конкретизации, уменьшению вероятности ошибок и производительности?

Система БЭМ мне нравится, но понятно все-таки далеко не все. Буду благодарен, если кто приведет css-стили для подобной разметки:

```
<header class="header">
<img class="logo">
<form class="search-form">
    <input type="input">
    <button type="button"></button>
</form>
<ul class="lang-switcher">
    <li class="lang-switcher__item">
        <a class="lang-switcher__link" href="url">en</a>
    </li>
    <li class="lang-switcher__item">
        <a class="lang-switcher__link" href="url">ru</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</header>
```

Почему, например, `logo` вместо `header__logo`?

Comment: [вес селекторов] http://habrahabr.ru/post/137588/

[бэм] https://ru.bem.info/methodology/

Comment: Глянул, но там есть моменты, описанные не полностью. Т.е. там может быть элемент с классом sth и внутри него элемент с классом sth__elem и тогда понятно, как писать css-стили. Но там в дереве есть и header с вложенным search и примера css для такого случая нет

Comment: Насчет веса селекторов не понял. Т.е. вообще. Ни саму статью, ни при чем тут она.

Comment: значит еще раз читайте, раз задаете такой вопрос 
.callus {}

#header .callus {}

.header-top .callus {}

#header .header-top .callus {}

и не понимаете разницы!!!

Comment: Во-первых, спокойнее.
Во-вторых, статья о том, как разные селекторы влияют на элемент. А вопрос был о вложенности селекторов и какой вариант лучше. Вот БЭМ по теме.

Answer (score 3):

Не мудрить и делать как проще.

1. Имя достаточно точно характеризует элемент?

   - Да — перейти к п. 2.
   - Нет — переименовать, затем перейти к п. 2.
2. Может быть несколько таких элементов?

   - Да — Они все должны выглядеть одинаково?

     - Да — использовать только класс.
     - Нет — использовать вложенность.
   - Нет — использовать только класс.

> Второй вариант ... при большом уровне вложенности движок делает большой путь

Это самая распространённая и самая оптимизированная операция. Она почти бесплатна.

Comment: @Arhad, в js тернарный оператор такой же ;)